# Swift send a Youtube Link to a URL

Tags: ios, swift

My friend created a web app which plays some music videos etc. I created an iOS app that shows a webview from that web app.

We want that when people press on share on Youtube that our app sends this Youtube link to a specific URL so that the web app can add this video to their playlist.

I tried a little bit with share extension but I think I'm doing something wrong.

```
if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem {
    if let itemProvider = item.attachments?.first as? NSItemProvider {
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {
            itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.url", options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) -> Void in
                if let shareURL = url as? NSURL {
                    print("thats the ",shareURL)

                }
                self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler:nil)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like what you need to do is simply pass the the URL as a variable. This can be easily done in PHP. This might be helpful: http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Comment: I need this for Swift.I want to send the URL/link  (maybe as a String ?) to the webapp trough my ios app

Comment: Yes this is possible. Your friend would need to make his script support passing of variables through URLs. You would simply request a URL via the Swift app. A PHP URL looks like this: http://example.com/home.php?myvar=youtubelink.

Comment: My friend created this.I just need to pass the youtube link from the share extension to this url > http://example.com/home.php?myvar=youtubelink. How can i get this ? :-) IOS App > Displays Webapp > User uses share extension on Youtube > Link send to Ios App > Ios App sends to Webapp (php)

Comment: I can take a look t how you would implement this if you supply some more source code. Specifically, the action (function) of the share button on iOS and also the website URL so I can inspect how you are implementing the playlist queue.